# How to install phantom.js on codeigniter project?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, phantomjs

Hello i want to use phantom.js in my codeigniter project. I've downloaded the zip from github and in the foleder i found phnatomjs.exe but don;t know what to do with it. I mean it's not like other jquery when you just embed it on your project file header. How can i install it? I don't use node.js in my project.

Comment: What do you think phantom.js will do for you?

Comment: It will help me evaluate some page. I use i'll use it with mocha and expect.js

Comment: You mean testing? Yes, phantomjs is capable of that, but that has nothing to do with your web development framework. PhantomJS works directly on the page as a separate process since it is essentially a browser.

Comment: I need phantom.js to run a test file which response i must get from ajax post. So i sent some code from ajax post to that file which contain mocha.js runner and i want to get whether the code contain some error or not.Unfortunately the response only return the static content which mean my javascript assertion isn't run and then i read that phantom.js capable of doing the headless testing. But i don't know how to integrate it with my project which using codeigniter framework.